# Windows - making cmd see PATH changes

Tags: batch-file, path, cmd

I have a bunch of batch files which I want to run sequentially. One of them runs an MSI which adds a folder to the `PATH`. How can I make sure that subsequent batch files will notice this change, without restarting CMD? I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.

I've tried `call`, `cmd /c` and `start ""`, in the hope that starting a new process will work, but it doesn't.

```
in run-both-scripts.bat
call script1.bat  <-- This runs an MSI which modifies the PATH
call script2.bat  <-- This relies on the PATH changes which were made by the MSI in script1.bat
```

---

To clarify: this is fairly straightforward to reproduce.

1. Start CMD
2. Create an environment variable *manually*, not using `setx`, to mimic what the MSI does.

   1. Right click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment variables -> New
   2. Create an environment variable called, say, `hello` with the value `hi there`.
3. In your CMD window, type `echo %hello%`. You'll get `%hello%`.
4. Try `cmd /c "echo %hello%`. You'll get `%hello%`.
5. Try `start ""` to open a new CMD process; type `echo %hello%`. You'll get `%hello%`.
6. Try `start "" echo %hello%` to run the command in a new CMD process. You'll get `%hello%`.
7. Finally, try *manually* opening a new CMD window from the Start menu and type `echo %hello%` from there. You'll see `hi there`.

So you can see that the only way I've been able to make CMD see the change to the environment variable is by restarting CMD.

Comment: `without restarting CMD` ? every batch will restart cmd ....

Comment: @Endoro If you start them by clicking on them in explorer, yes. Not if you're typing their names at the command line, or automating them in another batch file.

Comment: simply save the path variable in a text file and compare it at the batch start.

Comment: @Endoro I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Show your code where you set the PATH, and also where you call the subsequent batch scripts. You shouldn't have to do anything special.

Comment: @dbenham the `PATH` is set by an MSI, which is run by one of the batch files.

Comment: If `script1.bat` have a `setlocal` command, remove it.

Comment: Does an `echo %PATH%` in `script1.bat` after running the MSI show the modified path? If it does, you may have a `setlocal` in it as Aacini suspected. If it doesn't, you need to change the line `call script2.bat` to `start "" script2.bat`, so that the second script runs in a separate process (thus re-reading the environment).

Comment: Addendum: of course that should have been `start "" /wait script2.bat` in my last comment.

Comment: I've already tried all of these suggestions. None of them have worked for me. Please see my edit; I've put some more detail about the exact nature of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, did some research, and found out why the soloutions we've been throwing at you don't work. When you start cmd.exe as an application, it looks at the current environment variables and copies it to memory. When you start cmd in a batch file, it will not look at the environment variables, instead it will look at the variables set in the current batch file, and utilise those. Thats the problem when your storing data on memory. The only way this is possible is if you copy the current environment variables into a text file as memory on a hard disk. Now, the question is how to go about doing this.

After heavy research, the only thing I could find that related to the topic was the use of `start /i`, however, when I tested this it didn't work. (`start /?` for more info).

In other words, other the `setx`, I don't think this is possible with batch.

Mona

Comment: I've already tried this and it hasn't worked. Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: @poorsod: Read my new answer.

Comment: That sucks :( Thanks for the help anyway.